# Avoid instanceof in Java with subclasses having additional fields

Tags: java, oop

I recently was working on a code base that used an excessive amount of instanceof checks all over the code and I'm wondering if there would have been a better way to refactor it.

As an example there was a class AbstractTender, and it had several subclasses, CreditDebitTender, CheckTender, GiftCardTender, StoreCreditTender, etc. Each of these classes added several fields, methods, and its own logic. This resulted in checks all over the code like the following.

Is there a better way to avoid all the instanceof checks all over the code base given there is a significant difference between the super class and sub classes IE in some cases many more and very different fields / methods? Just as a sample maskedCardNumber and authCode are specific only to credit debit tenders, and micr is specific to only check tender.

```
if (tender instanceof CreditDebitTenderIfc) {
    // insert tender into credit debit tender table
}

if (tender instanceof CheckTenderIfc) {
    // insert tender into check tender table
}

if (tender instance of GiftCardTenderIfc) {
    // inser tender into gift card tender table
}

// etc
```

FYI: This was a very old code base, original product is over 10 years old.

Comment: Hard to say with only the instanceof lines, but usually polymorphism is useful to solve instanceofs

Comment: Agree about polymorphism but that seems to be more difficult when there is a large difference between the data and methods a CreditDebitTender carries vs a CheckTender.

Comment: Just to echo the comments above, here's the pattern: [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism.](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html)  Your code probably needs a to define an `AbstractTender.insertTender()` method which is then overridden to provide specific behavior.

Comment: @markspace That could definitely work, but I could see that being a trade of as well, because now that class is handling persistence instead of having a layered approach. Although I suppose it could delegate the persistence to another another component.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed 'table' meant Map, but if you're writing to a database I think that code should be separated into its own layer.  There's a pattern for that too: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/transferobject-139757.html

Answer (score 1):

I can think on two ways to do it:

1. Define an abstract method in `AbstractTender` called `save`. Each subclass has to implement how the info should be stored in the database.
2. If `AbstractTender` and subclasses are entity classes and cannot have repository logic, and if you use Java 8, you can make use of a `Map<Class, Consumer<AbstractTender>>` where each value of the map focuses on how to store the instance of `AbstractTender`. You may look for the specific element using the class of the instance.

   Brief example:

   ```
   Map<Class, Consumer<AbstractTender>> mapTenderStoreFunc = new HashMap<>();
   mapTenderStoreFunc.put(CreditDebitTenderIfc.class, tender -> {
           CreditDebitTenderIfc cdTender = (CreditDebitTenderIfc)tender;
           //logic goes here...
       });
   mapTenderStoreFunc.put(CheckTenderIfc.class, tender -> {
           CheckTenderIfccdTender ctifc = (CheckTenderIfc)tender;
           //logic goes here...
       });
   //and on...
   ```

   Then your `save` method will use the map like this:

   ```
   public void save(AbstractTender tender) {
       Consumer<AbstractTender> saveOperation = mapTenderStoreFunc.get(tender.getClass());
       if (saveOperation != null) {
           saveOperation.accept(tender);
       } else {
           //maybe throw an exception
           //or log a warning, error or something to notice!
       }
   }
   ```

   The downside of this approach is that if somebody in the team forgets to add the proper mapping for a child class, then you're in trouble.
3. Similar approach of 2, but if you use Java 7 or prior, instead of a `Consumer<AbstractTender>` you may define your own interface and fill it with anonymous classes:

   ```
   interface TenderRepository {
       void save(AbstractTender tender);
   }

   Map<Class, TenderRepository> map = new HashMap<>();
   map.put(CreditDebitTenderIfc.class, new TenderRepository() {
           @Override
           public void save(AbstractTender tender) {
               CreditDebitTenderIfc cdTender = (CreditDebitTenderIfc)tender;
               //logic goes here...
           }
       });
   ```

Comment: The save method can look up the parent class if the child key is not found, allowing for true polymorphism. I don't necessarily recommend doing this, just saying it's possible.

Comment: The map should have `Class<? extends AbstractTender>` as it's first type parameter to avoid someone putting arbitrary classes into the map. In addition, to avoid null checks, you *could* take advantage of `Map::getOrDefault`: `Consumer<AbstractTender> saveOperation = map.getOrDefault(tender.getClass(), t -> {throw new IllegalArgumentException("No save operation for " + t.getClass());});`, though you can't throw checked exceptions since it's inside a lambda. Also, arguable if it improves readability, certainly not as a one-liner in a SO comment. Just pointing out it's possible :^)

Answer (score 1):

As per the code given its sure that tender object has been created already.
The object can be any one of the subclass objects.
So one can use call back behavior.

```
public abstract class AbstractTender{

abstract void insert();

}

public class CreditDebitTenderIfc extends AbstractTender{
@Override
public void insert(){
  // insert tender into credit debit tender table
}
}

class Main{

public void doOperation(AbstractTender tender){
       tender.insert();
}

}
```

As you have already tender object, just call
tender.insert();
it will call appropriate subclass method.